# Добавить "обои" в JAVA проект и дальше еще немного

Tags: java

Ребят, помогите престарелому студенту. 
Будет много вопросов, но для начала, как добавить BG в настоящий проект.

- Создан класс
- Графический файл помещен в тут же папку что и класс
- Вот код

  ```
  package test_GUI_lab_3;

  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;

  public class bacgGround extends JFrame {

      private Image img;

      JPanel background = new JPanel() {
          public void paint (Graphics g){
              g.drawImage(img,0,0,getSize().width,getSize().height,this);
              super.paint(g);
          }
      };

      public bacgGround(String str) {
          //...

          ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("bg.jpg");
          img=icon.getImage();

          //...

          Color transparent = new Color(0, true);
          background.setBackground(transparent);
      }

  }
  ```

В итоге, картинка не показывается.
Где ошибка?

Comment: А почему бы не поменять местами строчки

    g.drawImage(img,0,0,getSize().width,getSize().height,this);

и

    super.paint(g);

?

Вот вам [код с братского сайта](http://stackoverflow.com/a/523818/276994).

Answer (score 1):

В своё время сталкивался с этим же. Не уверен, что это именно то, что нужно. Но у меня работает именно так. Во-первых, я использовал обычный Image и вносил его с помощью ImageIO (Image были объявлены выше). Дальше растягивал под размер экрана с помощью getScaledInstance. И потом рисовал его непосредственно на панели. Опять же. Я не уверен, насколько это модно, современно и правильно, но вот мой код:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("images/background.jpg"));
        img2 = ImageIO.read(new File("images/sun.png"));
        img3 = ImageIO.read(new File("images/cloud.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    img = img.getScaledInstance((int)scrW, (int)scrH, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    g2.drawImage(img2, (int) (scrW/2-200), 20, null);
    g2.drawImage(img3, (int) (scrW/2), 150, null);
    g2.drawImage(img3, (int) (scrW/2-500), 100, null);
}
```

**P.S.**
Да, кстати, неоднократно читал, что переопределение метода paint - не лучшая затея. В данном случае, как я понимаю, ни на что не повлияет. Но, если используете Swing, лучше переопределять paintComponent

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы.
Не работает ни один способ.
Ребят, я еще практически ноль в Java - вы показываете свои коды, и помогаете мой модефицировать - но ничего не работает (((
Vendetta8247 - я свой код преобразовал под твой алгоритм - не идет. Ты моежшь полную раскладку дать???

Answer (score 0):

А попробуй к своей панельке применить метод setOpaque(false). У меня в таких же условиях после этого метода начала отображаться картинка фоном для JTree, только цвет бэкграунда я не задавал.

Comment: Можешь код выправить? Уже мозг кипит.....

Comment: Это, вроде, не весь код - метода main не вижу, а вполне возможно придётся в нём дописывать. Кстати, ты можешь не создавать лишний объект JPanel внутри твоего класса, ты ж от JPanel наследуешь. Так даже проще будет. А вот метод paint переопределить придётся, запишешь его просто как метод и всё.Суть проста - после создания объекта JPanel или твоего класса, если ты таки уберешь лишний JPanel внутри класса, у тебя добавится одна строчка всего - panel.setOpaque(false); ну или как у тебя называется объект твоего класса или панелька.

Comment: А вообще я бы написал так:
public class BacgGround extends JFrame {
    private Image img;
    BacgGround(){
    super();
    this.setOpaque(false);
//твой код из конструктора, только заместо объекта background у тебя будет this
    }
    public void paint (Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(img,0,0,getSize().width,getSize().height,this);
    super.paint(g);
    }
}